# How can I password-protect my workgroup?

Tags: networking, network-shares, password-management

I am using Windows XP SP2 and want to password-protect my LAN workgroup. By "password-protected," I mean workgroup users should be able to access each others' computers without passwords, but users who are not in the workgroup should be unable to access the group's shared documents.

How can I set my workgroup up this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm...
What is your network topology? it's most important part:)

Not sure what you exactly mean "...the pc in a workgroup can access each other..."
access the shared files?

1. NAS and setup workgroup folder with workgroup folder permissions
2. Server with active directory
3. if you share files from your PC, try to setup your PC with specific workgroup name "myworkgroup" for sure all PC's, you want to allow access from, must have same workgroup name.

But simplest and less expensive is NAS (Network attached storage)

The benefits are:

1. Easy manage access permissions
2. You keep your vital sensitive data out from computer (Disaster recovery plan)
3. You can setup and configure folders, access permissions,users on the fly without IT support over the web interface.

Regards,

Dmytry